# Ускорить/Оптимизировать

Tags: java, mysql

Необходимо получить все данные игрока из базы данных, для проверки насколько это быстро произойдет я создал цикл из 100 юзеров.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Начал:");
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println("user_" + i);
        RPlayer p = new RPlayer("user_" + i);
        p.getInfractions();//Получение значений из базы данных
        p.getLocalization();//Получение значений из базы данных
        p.getGroup();//Получение значений из базы данных
        p.getAuth();//Получение значений из базы данных
        p.getLevel();//Получение значений из базы данных
        p.getKarma();//Получение значений из базы данных
        p.getCoins();//Получение значений из базы данных
    }
    System.out.println("Заняло:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
```

Результат этого кода: https://hastebin.com/ibiwapiwuv.css

Время выполнения цикла заняло 23412 миллисекунд.

Во всех выше методах я использовал вот такую конструкцию:

```
public class RLevel {
private String player;
private Integer level;
private Integer xp;

private Statement statement;

public RLevel(RPlayer rPlayer) {
    this.player = rPlayer.getName();
    try {
        this.statement = Core.getInstance().getSqlConnector().getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet result = this.statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM level WHERE user = '" + this.player + "'");
        if (result.next()) {
            this.level = result.getInt("level");
            this.xp = result.getInt("xp");
        } else {
            this.level = 0;
            this.xp = 0;
            insert();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void insert() {
    try {
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO level VALUES (user, level, xp) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user='" + this.player + "', level=" + this.level + ", xp=" + this.xp);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void update() {
    try {
        this.statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE level SET level='" + this.level + ", xp=" + this.xp + "' WHERE user='" + this.player + "'");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Integer getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public void setLevel(Integer count) {
    this.level = count;
    update();
}

public void levelUp() {
    level++;
    update();
}

public Integer getXp() {
    return this.xp;
}

public void setXp(Integer count) {
    this.xp = count;
    update();
}

public void addXp(Integer count) {
    this.xp = + count;
    update();
}
```

}

В чем моя ошибка?
Почему запрос бд занимает такое большое количество времени?

Comment: Покажите класс: Core. Возможно этим .getInstance().getSqlConnector() вы создаете каждый раз новое подключение. + поле user может быть у Вас неиндексированное в таблице level.

Comment: .getInstance().getSqlConnector() 
Я получаю уже инициализированое подключение к базе данных.

Comment: Как понять неиндексированное?

Comment: То что инициализированное - это понятно, но одно ли? Может при каждом обращении новое создается?  У таблиц есть столбцы (первичные ключи, индексируемые и неиндексируемые), поиск быстро выполняется по первичным ключам и индексируемым столбцам.

Comment: покажите show create table level

Comment: statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS level(user varchar(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE, level int, xp int);");